# Conventional implementation of display-buffer-above-selected

Tags: window, display-buffer-alist

Despite respectable variety of `display-buffer-*` functions some of them stand out with lack of flexibility, such as `display-buffer-at-bottom` or [`display-buffer-below-selected`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html#index-display_002dbuffer_002dbelow_002dselected-2387) that exist in absence of reverse variant.

Assuming that decision was intentional, I would like to know what limitations are stopping these procedures from following the suit, or if there exists an easy way to create opposite implementation on the spot using existing inventory.

To make it more clear, here's my own attempt at making [`display-buffer-above-selected`](https://gist.github.com/myeffort/3526f886c494a9e2b5b9) which only exposes the duplication that lays burden on those that seek to replace missing functionality.

Comment: Here is a left and right example, which should be sufficient for you to see how to create your own function for above and/or below:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21544307/2112489  When using `window-in-direction` it is either `'above`, `'below`, `'left`, or `'right`.

Comment: Here is my own above example:  `(defun lawlist-display-buffer-above (buffer alist) (let ((window (cond ((get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame)) (get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame))) ((window-in-direction 'above) (window-in-direction 'above)) ((window-in-direction 'left) (window-in-direction 'left)) (t (selected-window))))) (window--display-buffer buffer window 'window alist display-buffer-mark-dedicated) (select-window (get-buffer-window (buffer-name buffer))) ))`  You will need to adjust the conditions to suit your needs.

Comment: Please consider sending your info about shortcomings, possible improvements, and suggestions for improvement (bug fixes or enhancement requests) to Emacs Dev, by using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: lawlist, can't help but point out, in case you find it useful, that `(cond (x x) (y y) (z z))` is the same as `(cond (x) (y) (z))` and also `(or x y z)`. Thanks for the advice, I will make use of it.

Comment: Drew, thanks for encouragement, I will make it so.

Comment: Thank you, myeffort, for broadening my horizons regarding shorthand ways to write code more efficiently -- greatly appreciated!  :)  I always enjoy learning new things.

Comment: @myeffort: I agree with your criticism, but it would be more useful to post it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.